# Diagram on a web page with Changing Values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a diagram which will display the IOPS between a hypervisor and a SAN on a web page (c# mvc web application), to show how much data transfer activity there is on a monitoring system.

For example something like this, however in this example the IOPS would be between the Hypervisor and the Virtual Machine:

[image]

Two part question:

1) Is there a free software package to create such a diagram where I can put dynamically changing values into a specific place?

2) If Q1 isn't feasible, is it possible to overlay the dynamic values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is looking at drawing the diagram out in SVG. Something like [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/) should do just fine. It is free and open source.

You are able to add IDs and classes onto the elements in there as well so that you can access them in the standard JQuery way.

If you are feeling adventurous, you could draw it out using [D3 here](https://d3js.org/)
which is for all your unique type charts and graphs.

Comment: Playing around with Inkscapre first, may give D3 ago in a bit - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the software but it can be achieved by ws protocol HTML5 with java SSE(server send event).

On client side you can use a static image for the values which are not changing dynamically and place any html element and change its value dynamically via jquery.

Use this only when you are aware of comet technology and have extra time.

Comment: Thank you, ideally software as Reflamer suggested, will look into HTML5 and Java SSE for more complex diagrams.